# Android XML: Unable to vertically align TextViews inside TableRow despite setting their android:gravity to "center_vertical"

Tags: android, xml

In my Android XML layout, I have a `TableLayout` that contains three cells of equal width (all have weight 1): the first two cells are `TextView`s and the last cell is a LinearLayout that has two `ImageButton`(s). However, right now, as shown in the screenshot below, the `TextView`s are vertically aligned to the top instead of vertically aligning to the center of the `TableRow`.

[image]

This seems strange, considering that I have specified `android:gravity` to `center_vertical` for the `TextView`(s). Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Area"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_icon_foreground" />

        <ImageButton
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/remove_icon_foreground" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity` affects the contents of the view on which it is applied. That is, for `TextView`, it aligns the text within the view's bounds.

To align the view itself within the parent, use `android:layout_gravity`. Or, use `android:gravity` on the `TableRow`.